# Use Selenium to press tab and then write with java

Tags: java, selenium, tabs, focus, element

I want selenium to press "TAB" for me and then write something in the focused field, now I know that I can use

```
sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
```

But as I understand it That require a locator behind it, I want to test the tab order of my page and to do so, I want to be able to focus on my first element only, then tab my way through the page like this:

```
--THE ELEMENTS IN THE TAB ORDER THEY ARE SUPOSED TO BE--
String[] elementArray = {"firstname","lastname", "phone", "email"};

for(int x = 0; x < 4; x = x+1) 
{
    WebElement theElement = driver.findElement(By.id(elementArray[x]));  
    if (x == 0) {driver.theElement.sendKeys(x)}
    else{driver.(TheCurrentlyFocusedElement).sendKeys(x)}

    String elementval = theElement.getAttribute("value");
    assertEquals(x, elementval);            
    (TheCurrentlyFocusedElement).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}
```

So the question is, is there a method I can use that allows me to use the currently focused element as a locator? i.e.:

```
driver.focusedElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB); ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for -
`driver.switchTo().activeElement();`

Answer (score 0):

I have just had to do something similar but found that sending tab didn't actually change focus (it did when manual testing, just not via Selenium).

I wanted to prove the order of input fields on screen (positioning was more important then tabbing in this case), so had to do something like the following;

```
String[] elementArray = {"firstname","lastname", "phone", "email"};

List<WebElement> inputFields = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input"));


for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
{
    assertEquals(elementArray[x], inputFields.get[x]);
}
```

I would probably create a list rather than an array, and compare those, but you should get the gist.

Yes, I know that this is quite a simplified approach and that this doesn't actually prove that  fields are definitely in that order once rendered, but it gives you some security for regression.

Comment: yes, I would to but the thing is all things in the tab order wont be input fields so there will be a mix of inputs, and buttons and select boxes

Comment: Sure, as I said, this was a simple solution of a relatively simple website.  When the Tab failed to automate (sure it's an issue with the site, not selenium), this was the best I could come up with.